# Tkinter IntVar() and DoubleVar() error in Python 3.8.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I was writing a program to show Integer Value from Entry using Tkinter and python 3.8.2
but it's not working when I enter zero before the number and also if I enter 08 its show error and if i enter 8 it's working
here's the code `

```
from tkinter import *

win = Tk()
win.geometry("300x400")
win.title("My Gui")
win.resizable(0, 0)
text_var = IntVar(win)  # DoubleVar(win)
show_var = StringVar(win)


def show():
    try:
        r = text_var.get()
        show_var.set(r)
    except:
        show_var.set("Enter Number only")


get_text = Entry(win, textvariable=text_var, bd=3).grid(row=0, column=0, padx=15, pady=15)
btn = Button(win, text="Click", activebackground="red", command=show).grid(row=0, column=1)
show_text = Label(win, textvariable=show_var).grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)

win.mainloop()
```

`
[image]

[image]

Comment: Python may treat the string starts with `0` as octal number.  So `04564` is valid octal number, but `0888` is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `lstrip` to remove the leading zeroes:

```
def show():
    try:
        r = text_var.get()
        r.lstrip('0')
        show_var.set(r)
    except:
        show_var.set("Enter Number only")
```

(strip removes both leading and trailing zeroes.)

Comment: I think OP wants to have zero before his/her integers.